# Crash when std::function is constructed from lambda returned value in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

This C++ code compiles successfully with VS 2012 but crashes at runtime:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f()
{
  std::cout << "f called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  auto get_f= []()
    {
        bool b = true;
        return b ? f : f;
    };

  std::function<void()> filter(get_f()); // crash here!!!
  return 0;
}
```

If we change get_f to this:

```
auto get_f= []()
{
   return f;
};
```

then program runs without crashes.

Is it a problem with this code or compiler/std library bug?

I have not tested with newer versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: You might have more luck on newer versions. The `<functional>` header got a big makeover recently IIRC.

Comment: VS 2013 update 4 is fine with this.

Comment: also VS 2015 is free for personal use :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like a problem with the standard library (or possibly compiler).

With VS 2013, it compiles and runs without a problem. If we add code to invoke the `filter` that runs as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f()
{
  std::cout << "f called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  auto get_f= []()
    {
        bool b = true;
        return b ? f : f;
    };

  std::function<void()> filter(get_f()); // crash here!!!
  filter();
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `f called`